# Multiline textview while keeping layout fixed

Tags: android, textview, multiline, android-layout-weight

I want to implement multiline textview keeping fixed layout. 
This is the expected output screen
[image: image 1].

And this is output i'm getting [image: image2].

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_product_desc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_product_title"
            style="@style/Appio.Text.Dark.Normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:maxLines="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_product_subtitle_or_model"
            style="@style/Appio.Text.Dark.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_product_short_description"
            style="@style/Appio.Text.Dark.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_product_availability"
            style="@style/Appio.Text.Dark.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_product_cost"
        style="@style/Appio.Text.Primary.Normal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Even though i'm setting maxLine and assigning weight property, layout does not remained fixed. And some of "**Out of Stock**" showing like in image 2. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `txt_product_cost` height to 0dp if you want to use weights.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_product_cost"
    style="@style/Appio.Text.Primary.Normal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

That should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing *android:layout_weight="0.20"* for the TextViwes in the first LinearLayout and changing *android:layout_height* to *wrap_content*

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on layout_weight here. Set layout_height to "wrap_content"